# show all data only group by specific rows : Select * from table group by column having column = 'value'

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I use mysql. My table look like this:

[image: my table]

Last I try to use this query

```
SELECT * FROM movie GROUP BY `group`  HAVING cateogry = 'TV'
```

I want with this query result as: show all but only GROUP BY TV category, where category = 'TV'

**I want this Result**
[image]

**But my query give me this result (HAVING in query work as WHERE clouse)**

[image]

IF I use this QUERY

```
SELECT * FROM movie GROUP BY `group`
```

It give me this result

[image]

I want -> QUERY -> GROUP BY `group` (ID no 9 and ID 1,2,3 treat as different group name)

> IF `group` has all same values BUT `category`='movie' (RETURN ALL ROWS
>   group by NOT APPLY)
>
> IF `group` has all same values BUT `category`='TV' (RETURN 1 ROW group by APPLY)

Comment: typo in your query: `cateogry` -> `category`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT min(ID) as ID, min(Name), `group`, Category
FROM movie
GROUP BY `group`, Category
ORDER BY ID
```

Comment: @user2511667 . . . As a note:  I don't believe this really works in general.  This returns the minimum id and the minimum name -- but not the name for the minimum id.  You seem to want the row with the minimum id (which is what my answer does), not two separate minimums.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff You are right, but i dont want minimum value, my result is, SELECT * FROM movie GROUP BY `group`, `Category`

Answer (score 3):

You seem to want this query:

```
select m.*
from movie m join
     (select `group`, min(id) as minid
      from movie
      group by `group`
     ) g
     on m.id = g.minid;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but this is not my answer,, Please check my first image with arrows, and i want 2nd image result,, now please tell me, what query you use to get 2nd image result,.. AND Best if you use GROUP by `group` with your query...

Comment: @user2511667 . . . I did and have again looked at your image and that is what this query should return.

Comment: with your query ID 9 not showing,, i change your query with where clouse but still not working,,,, You query result same as LAST image

Comment: Thank you soo much,, I change little bit in your query and i get my result... Thanks, :* what is change in query see my ANSWER

Comment: NO, sorry its not working,, i check properly,,if i  use where clause and remove ON m.id = g.minid all repeat result show,,if i use then ID 9 not showing,,

Comment: @user2511667 . . . If you want both `group` and `category` for the "groups", then they both need to be included in the `group by` clause.

Comment: Please add some explanation to this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the below? I think you are pretty close. As when you are grouping your 'group' t. You are also grouping the one whose category is movie as well. So you just need to create a separate group Category.

```
SELECT * FROM movie
WHERE group = 't'
GROUP BY group, Category
ORDER BY ID
```